# C# ListView from Another Function

Tags: c#

Please forgive me for such a stupid question. I am sure many of you will find this easy, where I have sent almost half the day reading trying to figure this out.

Here is the problem:

1. I have a FORM (Form1.cs) made. In that form I created a listview, and named it "ListView1".
2. Within the Form1.cs, I call a function called FileManager(this), where I pass in the THIS object.
3. In FileManager.cs I was able to listviewArray=  originalForm.Controls.Find("listView1", true) and find that 'listview'.
4. When I do a listviewArray[0]<-- I can't seem to add a list to it.

FileManager.cs

```
FileManager(object sender)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            originalForm = (Form)sender;
        }


    }
    public void getFiles()
    {
        filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(hsocDir);
        if(filePaths != null)
        {
            listviewArray=  originalForm.Controls.Find("listView1", true);
            if(listviewArray != null)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("text");

                // My Array is listViewArray
                // How to add things to Lvi to it.

            }
        }


== Form1.cs
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(`enter code here`);
            mysql = new MySQLCheck(this);
            fileManager = new FileManager(this);
            fileManager.getFiles();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access element 0 of the collection because the collection is empty. To add an item, use:

```
listViewArray.Items.Add(lvi);
```

You need to modify the `Items` collection instead of the `ListView` itself for this to work, as `ListView` is not a collection (its a control).

Comment: Question 1: Is the method I use to FIND the listView1 object the right route when trying to add things to it?

Comment: @user3443386 Thats a pretty reasonable method. Even better would be to toss out the direct UI manipulation and use an MVVM implementation (likely with WPF). That being said, you probably aren't ready to re-write your project, so it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
listViewArray.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Also in your listview,setting this properties will help :

```
        // Set the view to show details.
        listViewArray.View = View.Details;
        // Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
        listViewArray.FullRowSelect = true;
        // Display grid lines.
        listViewArray.GridLines = true;
```